# Logging multiple threads (Spring and RabbitMQ)?

Tags: spring, logging, log4j, rabbitmq

I´m working in a Spring/RabbitMQ project. My problem is to identify the process Log, because 2 consumers of the queue are logging the same thread name (Thread:SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1). What is best practice in this cases?

We are using Spring/RabbitMQ/Log4J.

Comment: What makes you think two threads have the same name?

Comment: Both are logging Thread:SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1